# Creating remote video media entity programmatically not generating thumbnail

Tags: media, 9

Using Drupal 9.4.1, I am creating a remote video media entity programmatically and for some reason the title and thumbnail are not being created. They are created when cron runs so in my terminal when I run `drush cron` I get these errors:

```
$ drush cron
  [notice] Starting CPC XML Import
  [warning] Illegal offset type UrlResolver.php:154
  [warning] Illegal offset type in isset or empty UrlResolver.php:155
  [warning] Illegal offset type UrlResolver.php:167
  [warning] Illegal offset type UrlResolver.php:168
```

The file that is producing this error is: /core/modules/media/src/OEmbed/UrlResolver.php

The media entities are created and attached to the node, however, no thumbnail and no title on the media entity.

An example URL I am using to create these entities is: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1r4wuc_oGwY`

If I create the remote video entity through the media library UI, it creates it no problem. Thumbnail is generated and title is imported from YT.

My code is below:

```php
    // Add Video Gallery Videos.
    if ($product_data->xpath('./marketing_content/content[@type="gallery-video"]')) {
      foreach ($product_data->xpath('./marketing_content/content[@type="gallery-video"]/content') as $video) {
        $link = $video->media->source; // This is the youtube link.
        $video = self::upsertVideo($link);
        $product->field_videos->appendItem(['target_id' => $video->id()]); // This works, it adds the media entity to the node.
      }
    }
```

and then here is my upsertVideo function:

```php
    /**
     * Load or create a media type of remote_video based off of the URL.
     *
     * @param string $link
     *   A link to the video on CPC feed.
     *
     * @return \Drupal\media\Entity\Media
     *   The existing or newly created media entity.
     */
    private static function upsertVideo($link) {
      $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('media')
        ->condition('bundle', 'remote_video')
        ->condition('field_media_oembed_video', $link)
        ->execute();

      // Video found, return it.
      if (count($query) > 0) {
        $video = Media::load(reset($query));
        return $video;
      }

      // Create a new Remote Video media entity.
      $video = Media::create([
        'bundle' => 'remote_video',
        'uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
        'field_media_oembed_video' => [
          'value' => $link,
        ],
      ]);

      $video->setPublished(TRUE)->save();

      return $video;
    }
```

Comment: Drupal\media\OEmbed\UrlResolver::getResourceUrl is being passed an illegal $url parameter. I think it expects a string. Have you attached a debugger?

Comment: the value of $link is a string. Adding a logger of `\Drupal::logger('test')->notice('url is ' . $url);` to the top of getResourceUrl() produces the same log with a `[notice] url is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1r4wuc_oGwY`

Comment: Those are language warnings, not Drupal.

Comment: I understand that. I am passing a string as far as I can tell.

Comment: Printing something is not the same as knowing its type. I’m saying you should var_dump $link.

Comment: It is indeed a string. `string(43) "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1r4wuc_oGwY"`

Comment: What type of field is field_media_oembed_video?

Comment: @Clive is it just Text (plain). Its the default "Remote video" entity type that comes with media

Comment: @cilefen was correct. Not sure where I had my var_dump before that was giving me a string, but when I did `gettype($url)` it was my simpleXMLObject. The fix was to cast it as a string `$link = (string) $video->media->source; // This is the youtube link.`

Comment: I posted an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$link` is likely an object. Cast it to a string because it is used to dereference an array.